# emitting a message from nodejs server to python client

Tags: node.js, python-3.x, socket.io

## I'm looking for a way to emit an instruction from my NodeJS server to my client Python.

## My server receive the 'instruction' from a flutter mobile application, and the connection works. But I am not able to emit this instruction to my client which is in Python.

## nodejs server

`socket.on('magnification', (dataSet) => {
console.log(dataSet);

```
io.emit('magnify', dataSet);
```

});`

## python client

`import socketio`

## Initialize the Socket.io client connection

`sio = socketio.Client()

`@sio.event` def connect():
print('Connected to Node.js server!')

@sio.event
def disconnect():
print('Disconnected from Node.js server!')`

## Listen for data from the server

`@sio.on('magnify') def on_report(data): print("hello world") print(data)`

sio.connect('http://localhost:8000')
sio.wait()